# How often is rank updated?

Tags: support, top-users

How often are the weekly rankings updated?  It looks like its not real time.

It would be nice if the rankings were a little more closer to real time.

Comment: I feel weird saying this, but given they are _weekly_, I wouldn't immediately assume that they are anything but.

Comment: I assume they are cached for a day and are refreshed on midnight, UTC based on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134528/158100)

Comment: Which rankings are we talking about here. The [users list on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/users)? That is updated in real time, but the *order* is cached for short periods of time.

Comment: The weekly rankings.

Comment: @JeffSloyer: that's still not clear. There is also [this weekly ranking](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow). Perhaps you can include a link?

Comment: Ah, yet another "I didn't get my instant gratification, so I'll go to Meta" post. Patience is a virtue. If your weekly ranking doesn't update every second, I assure you that your life will continue, your world won't come crashing down around you, and the planet will not stop revolving or orbiting. :-)

Comment: Wow.....  I was just curious....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not clear to me what ranking you are talking about. There are two distinct rankings where users are listed according to their reputation gain this week:

- The [*Users* tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week) - This is updated in real time to show the current reputation gained so far this week. The order the users are listed in is cached for a few minutes, so the order may look off if someone overtakes someone else. Wait 5 minutes and reload the page to see the order updated.
- The [*Top users* lists on StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow); these are updated once a day at 00:00 UTC.

Comment: Yeah I was talking about the Top user list.